# Serving MBtiles for Cesium consumption

Tags: qgis, javascript, mbtiles, cesium

I am trying to create custom mbtile for Cesium consumption.

I was able to create a mbtiles file in QGIS (zoom 0 to 16) using the QTiles plug-in. I tested the generated mbtiles file using mbviewer from mapbox and it worked fine. [mbviewer](https://github.com/mapbox/mbview)

```
node cli.js --port 9000 ~/tmp/starpeak_low_res.mbtiles Listening on http://localhost:9000
```

So to serve it to Cesium, I used mbtiles-server from npm to create a WMTS compatible server. Here is the link to the server [mbtiles-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mbtiles-server)

So in Cesium, all I had to do is add a a new imagery provider:

```
var high_res = layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.WebMapTileServiceImageryProvider({
    url : 'http://10.10.3.13:8030/starpeak_low_res/wmts',
    layer : 'starpeak_low_res',
    style: 'default',
    format : 'image/jpeg',
    tileMatrixSetID : 'GoogleMapsCompatible',
    maximumLevel: 16
}));
```

however, it takes a very very very long time for the images to load on Cesium but it's almost instant using mbviewer. The mbtiles file is 200 MB but I assume at different zoom levels only a portion of that file is fetched.

Just to make sure the issue is not with mbtiles-server, I downloaded the free low res sattelite mbtiles files from openmaptiles link here. [link](https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/tileset/satellite-lowres/). That mbtiles file is served fine it's instant loading at different zoom levels.

for reference I uploaded the mbtiles file here. Credits to  NAIP GEOTIFF from earthexplorer.usg.gov [generated mbtiles file](https://expirebox.com/download/508a56c2efb174fb7344273baeec1f7e.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XYZ Tile Server instead of WMTS.  I use several different one's depending on the platform. You can also skip the tile server and upload folder of tiles to S3 Bucket or Standard Wed Server.  http://someurl/Z/X/Y.png.  https://github.com/naturalatlas/tilestrata  or https://github.com/mojodna/tessera

Comment: Try an existing XYZ Tile server to see the performance. Use the Leaflet Providers to grab the URL of the Tile Servers https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/    for Example ESRI http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png  or one of my favorite http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg

Comment: Connect to XYZ tile Server via URL Template Imagery Provider https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/UrlTemplateImageryProvider.html

Comment: Why NOT use Terriajs instead of Cesium.  It's easy to add layers via a JSON catalog file.  It's based on Cesium

Comment: ok I will try it with XYZ tile servers, but I wanted to use mbtiles to ease uploading of areas for users. Also I need to host it offline so cannot do S3. I looked at TerriaJS and it seems like it supports vector tiling which I think Cesium doesn't support. I will try that as well.

Comment: Cesium and Terriajs ARE NOT offline Mapping Engines for Mobile Apps. They require a WebServer to run and a Tile Server to serve the MBTILES.  You could build that as part of a mobile app webview. But you'd be better off selecting an OpenGL Powered Native Solution like WhirlyGlobe/Maply or MapBox GL Native or Mapbox GL React Native

Comment: I am not working on a mobile app though. MapBoxGL also requires a Tile server anyways.

Comment: https://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/Imagery-Layers-Tutorial/#imagery-providers    Tile Map Service (TMS) - A REST interface for accessing map tiles. Tiles can be generated with MapTiler or GDAL2Tiles. In Cesium, see TileMapServiceImageryProvider.
OpenGIS Web Map Tile Service (WMTS) - An OGC standard for serving pre-rendered georeferenced map tiles over the Internet. In Cesium, see WebMapServiceImageryProvider.
OpenStreetMap - Access to OpenStreetMap tiles or any Slippy map tiles. There are several ways to host these tiles. In Cesium, see createOpenStreetMapImageryProvider.